# Необходимо удалить парные элементы в списке

Tags: python, list

Знаю про функцию set(), но она оставляет число.
То есть мне нужно удалить оба элемента.
Например, [1, 2, 3, 3, 2] необходимо преобразовать в [1].

Comment: если нервное количество раз - оставлять один?

Comment: А если какой-то элемент встречается более двух раз?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нужно удалить элементы, встречающиеся чётное количество раз, и оставить по одному элементу для тех, которые имеют нечётное число вхождений, то можно так:

```
from functools import reduce
l = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2]
res = reduce(lambda s, x: s ^ {x}, l, set())
```

Результат:

```
{1, 4, 5}
```

Comment: Красивое решение! `s - {x} if x in s else s | {x}` -> `s ^ {x}`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо за подсказку, поправил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Можно посчитать сколько раз встречается каждое число с помощью `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

data = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2]

counter = Counter(data)

uniqs = []

for x, num in counter.items():
    if num == 1:
        uniqs.append(x)
        
print(uniqs)
```

Это самое эффективное по скорости работы решение для общего случая. Впрочем, если нам известно про входные данные что-то особенное, то можно найти ещё более эффективные решения.

Например, если как в вашем случае, повторяющиеся элементы всегда парные, а уникальный элемент только один, то можно использовать хак с "исключающим или" и найти уникальный элемент за линейное время:

```
from itertools import accumulate
from operator import xor


data = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2]

uniq = accumulate(data, xor)

print(list(uniq)[-1])
```

Comment: Как вы считаете не нужно ли `if num == 1:` заменить на `if num % 2 == 1:`? Это соответствует удалению всех пар и оставлению только элементов без пары.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, это уже у автора надо спрашивать, чего именно он хочет.

Answer (score 1):

Для каждого элемента проверяем сколько раз он повторяется в списке. Если 1, то оставляем его.

```
[x for x in a if a.count(x) == 1]  # [1]
```

Comment: Это будет работать, но здесь квадратичная сложность. В то время, как есть решение с линейно-логарифмической сложностью. На больших исходных списках ваш вариант будет ощутимо дольше.

Comment: Есть линейное решение на хеш-таблицах.

Comment: @Xander, написал в лоб, думал 3 секунды